# Should I use a file or a database table to store parameters?

Tags: database, symfony, parameters, doctrine

I am building a Symfony application and I want to be able to configure it directly in the web platform (i. e. without having to change a file myself). To do this, I wanted to create global parameters with a key and a value. For instance, a key could be a string `emails` and the value an email list.

This can be done easily in Symfony using [parameter files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html) and reading/writing to this file with the application but I thought it might also be good to use a database and create a `parameter` table which would have 2 columns for the key and value.

What do you think in terms of design? Would it be better to use one rather than the other, or do you think it's not really important?

Edit: What I want is to have dynamic parameters that I can use in my application. For example I could change the color of the interface.

Comment: The database is not for saving application parameters.http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks I've already read the documentation. I should have been more specific. What I want is to be able to dynamically change "parameters" that my application will be using like the color of the interface or a list of emails to contact in case the user need to report something.

Comment: In that case yeah

Answer (score 2):

Use "parameters file (yml)" only for parameters that change between the development environment and the production environment.
So you can Backup and restore db without problems.

Use localStorage or Cookies for User configurations.

Use Database for site configurations that don't change between the development environment and the production environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in my case I should use the database according to what you said.

Comment: I think you must use parameter.yml. The database is not for saving application parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you need to make your current set of parameters accessible to your collegues working on your app with you. In case when you have parameter file, you could simply add it to your git repository, commit and pull to the remote. And how will you share it from your database? Definitely, it would include much more steps for you as for them. Also, what if you want to change your data storage from database to something else - than, you will need to define how to map your configuration entity to new storage again. According to that assumptions I would say that parameter files will suit this task better.

Comment: I'm indeed using a parameter file for parameters I don't need to change regularly. Here the need is different. Let's say I want to be able to change the color of the interface. With a file, I would need to: 1) Make the change; 2) Commit; 3) Deploy. It would be a long process just to make a tiny change and one that can be frequent. I think a parameter file shouldn't be changed when the application is running.

Comment: I belive since it is 1) not part of your app model domain; 2) it should be accessible right on application deploy; it shouldn't be stored in your database. Database shouldnt affect application configuration. And you are wrong on "With a file, I would need to: 1) Make the change; 2) Commit; 3) Deploy. It would be a long process just to make a tiny change and one that can be frequent." I belive it should be in git repository, but out of tracking system(in .gitignore in other words) - unless you dont want to share its versions. Writing CRUD for DB will be longer procces.

Comment: Moreover you ties your app to particular storage placing your configuration to DB. Image you want to change your storage - doesnt matter - you will need to have DB beacuse you store your config there - and this is bad approach in that case.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do in the first place. Using a parameter file that I would put in the `.gitignore` and make an interface so that user administrators would use the application to change the configuration. But it seems a bit weird that's why I asked. Also some projects like [Worpress uses a table to let their user change some settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options)

Comment: Yeah, I know, worked with Bitrix framework some time ago - they use the same approach as Wordpress - and that's wiered because every project becomes tightly coupled to DB with whole bunch of tables you do not even need or do not even consider their existence. I think that it's acceptable to have some config in DB in case, for example, if it's accessible by users so they could change the color of the site and save its values to access it on next visit, but even then it should duplicate and override global config in text file, but not entirely replace it accourding to what I said earlier.